# How come sizeHint() is QSize(-1, -1)?

Tags: qt, pyqt

For the following, I get `self.page1.sizeHint()` and `self.page1.minimumSizeHint()` both as `QSize(-1, -1)`. Does anyone know why? I was expecting the minimum size hint should be at least the size of the label.

```
    # ...
    self.page1 = QtGui.QWidget()
    self.page1.setObjectName("page_General")
    self.label_Server = QtGui.QLabel(self.page1)
    self.label_Server.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(20, 20, 39, 13))
    self.label_Server.setObjectName("label_Server")
    print self.page1.sizeHint(), self.page1.minimumSizeHint()
```

Thanks

Comment: @Thuga this look like answer to me.

Comment: @UmNyobe Turned it into an answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The default implementation of [`sizeHint()`](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qwidget.html#sizeHint-prop):

> This property holds the recommended size for the widget.
>
> If the value of this property is an invalid size, no size is
>   recommended.
>
> The default implementation of sizeHint() returns an invalid size if
>   there is no layout for this widget, and returns the layout's preferred
>   size otherwise.

Same goes for `minimumSizeHint`.